# Windows 10 installation stuck at purple screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-installation

A couple of days ago after updating Windows 10 (not upgrading to but updating) I mistakenly clicked on restart instead of shutdown so it restarted normally after which I shut it down. But the next afternoon when I started my PC it fails to boot and shows a black screen with a blinking underscore symbol. Like the one we see in command prompt or turbo C. After encountering this, I tried to reboot, pressing the f8 key, checking the cables and a lot but nothing hardware related seemed at fault.

After what would be like the 15th failed attempt I got an ISO file of Windows 10 x64 and attempted to install it at which it gets stuck at the purple screen and again to text or such display. However there momentarily appears a command prompt window on the screen which is fast so I can't read or catch it in my camera. However the install remains such at the purple screen. Any help to get my computer back and running would be great.

Edit: Aside from checking the PC, cables etc. I also have downloaded the ISO not twice but thrice and it doesn't seem to work with any of them. Also I am using my old faithful flash drive which I have used since a lot of time so it is definitely not the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

THis could either be a faulty ISO (DVD or USB) or WIndows checking your Hard Drives and getting stuck somewhere. Try the following: De-attach all your Drives (expect one DVD-Drive) and try to boot from the DVD or USB again. If you are able to get into setup now then re-attach your Hard Drive again, boot from any Live-DVD (Ultimate Boot CD for example http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ ) and save all your personal files. Then wipe the Hard Drive within the LIVE-DVD. Afterwards you should be able to get past the Purple Screen.